# showing error System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: unit-test

class...

```
public class ExceptionCreateExceptionRecord{
public static void insertException(Map<string, string> param)
    {    
    Exception__c newExcept              =   new Exception__c();
        newExcept.ExceptionTypeCode__c      =   param.get('ExceptionTypeCode__c');
        newExcept.RecordType.DeveloperName  =   'New Exception'; 


test class

    @isTest(SeeAllData=true)
    public class TestExceptionCreateExceptionRecord {
       static testmethod void Exception(){
        map<String ,String> parm=new map<String,String>();
            parm.put('ExceptionTypeCode__c', 'open');                
            parm.put('entry2','Second entry'); 
       ExceptionCreateExceptionRecord excep=new ExceptionCreateExceptionRecord();   
        ExceptionCreateExceptionRecord.insertException(Parm);
```

stacktrace

> Class.ExceptionCreateExceptionRecord.insertException: line 7, column
>   1( newExcept.RecordType.DeveloperName  =   'New Exception'; )
>   Class.TestExceptionCreateExceptionRecord.Exception: line 8, column 1(
>   ExceptionCreateExceptionRecord.insertException(Parm);)

Comment: Is this still an open question? You mentioned in some of the questions that your problem was solved but never accepted an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear from the other answers/comments that this is solved yet. The key point is that to set a record type you must relate the object to an already existing RecordType object by setting that already existing RecordType object's ID in the `RecordTypeId` field:

```
List<RecordType> rts = [
        SELECT Id FROM RecordType
        WHERE SobjectType = 'Exception__c'
        AND DeveloperName = 'New_Exception'
        ];
newExcept.RecordTypeId = rts[0].Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example you are trying to access RecordType's attribute DeveloperName  before even its declared.

> newExcept.RecordType.DeveloperName  =   'New Exception';

- First set the RecordType for the newExcept, then try setting the DeveloperName
- I am not sure why you are using RecordType.DeveloperName to set the Exception Name. It would be better to add a field in Exception__c called DeveloperName.

Comment: List<RecordType> lstRecordType = [SELECT id FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'Exception__c' AND DeveloperName  = 'New_Exception']; newExcept.RecordType.DeveloperName  =   'New Exception';

Comment: i set the record type